# Dealing with compounded article prefixes when sorting

Tags: articles

Say you are sorting a list of movie or book titles. You'll often want to pull certain articles from the front:

- Lord of the Rings, The
- Parisienne, La

What if you have a title like *L'École des Facteurs*? How would this be written?

- L'École des Facteurs
- École des Facteurs, L'
- École des Facteurs, La

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say:

> École des Facteurs, L'

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone have a source, maybe just a prominent site that does it this way?

Comment: @miracle2k: In an index the article is always placed at the end after a comma. Here the article is `L'` not `La`. See some information at http://theleme.enc.sorbonne.fr/cours/edition_epoque_moderne/etablissement_des_index

Answer (score 0):

The article is part of the title, it doesn't make sense to put it behind.
Would you use `Cain John, Mc`?

I would use `L'école des facteurs` as no one can think about `école des facteurs` alone.

Comment: The article is often pulled out of titles in such lists to make searching easier, otherwise half of the list would be in the T or L sections.

Comment: If your talking about software, it's not because you see it that it is a good solution. A lot of database search are done by autocompleting the results, ignoring the article. Like you begin to type "sei", it propose "le seigneur des anneaux" and "trois seigneurs"

Comment: I'm not talking about software, it's obviously irrelevant. What is relevant though is not making your user manually sift through 15 pages of "The [...]" when they could go straight to the relevant part of the title. Besides, it doesn't really answer the question. The OP is already separating the full articles and asks how to proceed for contracted ones.